# saving outlook express e-mails and contacts

Tags: windows, outlook-express

Is there a built in option? Is there an ideal way to back up all the e-mails, content, address book, and everything so that they can be re-imported to another machine? Is there a 3rd party application I should use?

Comment: So are you migrating to something other than Outlook Express?

Comment: I'd recommend going to Mozilla Thunderbird anyway, which is more portable across computers. Outlook Express has many limitations, including mail folder size limits, which in 2012 can happen more often than the old days of the 1990s.